# graphic tools to create custom graphics from templates and inputs

Tags: template, digital-printing

I want to make a custom timeline and print it out to put up on the wall. The size I have in mind is 10 ft by 3 ft. Each element in the timeline has a title, body, and image.

The image is a png and resized to 500x500
The title is limited to 30 characters
The body is limited to 600 characters

In total i have 63 elements for my timeline. I want to know if any tools exist that can take in the image, title, and body and auto generate the panels of the timeline from a template.

Or is there another more ideal way to do this?

Comment: Not aware of such an autogeneration timeline tool - but I *did* notice you talking about a wall print of 10' x 3', and then saying that your images will be  ***max 500 px x 500 px*** - which makes them ***1.6" x 1.6" at 300 ppi, or 3.3" x 3.3" at 150 ppi***, and if people will be approaching this wall timeline *closely* to look at it, you want the image quality to be pretty high for close up viewing - at least 200 ppi. I used to do tradeshow booths, where 300 ppi is for HD prints, screened panel images can go lower - [as low as 150 ppi] but the critical measure is how *close* your viewer gets.

Comment: @GerardFalla, Nice okay ill do some resizing to maybe 1200 by 1200 at 300 ppi Do you know if something like adobe indesign could be used for this?

Comment: Yes, Adobe InDesign or even Illustrator can accomplish the task ***un***-*automated*, as could Affinity Designer or Affinity Publisher (beta) - you could probably write scripts or more simply record actions / macros in Illustrator,  InDesign or Designer to repeat this set of tasks another time.

Comment: @GerardFalla Ill accept that as an answer if you post it

Comment: OK - have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not currently aware of such an autogeneration timeline tool - but I *did* notice you were talking about a wall print of 10' x 3', and then saying that your images will be ***max 500 px x 500 px*** - which makes them ***1.6" x 1.6" at 300 ppi, or 3.3" x 3.3" at 150 ppi***, and if people will be approaching this wall timeline *closely* to look at it, you want the image quality to be pretty high for close up viewing - at least 200 ppi. I used to do tradeshow booths, where 300 ppi is for HD prints, screened panel images can go lower - [as low as 150 ppi] but the critical measure is how *close* your viewer gets.

Adobe InDesign or even Illustrator can accomplish the task ***un***-*automated*, as could Affinity Designer or Affinity Publisher (beta) - you could probably write scripts or more simply record actions / macros in Illustrator, InDesign or Designer to repeat this set of tasks another time.